# Split large xslt into smaller ones

Tags: xslt, split

I have a large xslt file that is giving problems during deployment

com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.ClassGenException: Branch target offset too large for short
        at com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.BranchInstruction.dump(BranchInstruction.java:99)
        at com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.InstructionList.getByteCode(InstructionList.java:980)
        at com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.MethodGen.getMethod(MethodGen.java:616)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Mode.compileNamedTemplate(Mode.java:556)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Mode.compileTemplates(Mode.java:566)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Mode.compileApplyTemplates(Mode.java:818)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Stylesheet.compileModes(Stylesheet.java:615)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Stylesheet.translate(Stylesheet.java:730)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:370)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:445)

For this, I need to split this large xslt into smaller ones.
I've seen xsl:include tag, but seems like this works for seperate templates.

In my case, its a single parent tag with multiple assignments like this

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<ns5:taskListResponse>
  <xsl:for-each select="/tns:taskListResponse/task:task">
    <ns7:task>
      <xsl:if test="task:title">
        <ns7:title>
          <xsl:value-of select="task:title"/>
        </ns7:title>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="task:taskDefinitionURI">
        <ns7:taskDefinitionURI>
          <xsl:value-of select="task:taskDefinitionURI"/>
        </ns7:taskDefinitionURI>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="task:creator">
        <ns7:creator>
          <xsl:value-of select="task:creator"/>
        </ns7:creator>
      </xsl:if>
      ........100 more tags like this.....
      ...................
      </xsl:for-each>
</ns5:taskListResponse>
```

How can I split this xsl?
I want to put some tags in another file and include those inside the 
Appreciate your help

Regards
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

I would consider splitting this up into separate templates, for example each of the if tests could be replaced by `apply-templates`, and the following template to do the work:

```
<xsl:template match="task:*">
  <xsl:element name="ns7:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

If you don't need to re-order the children then the entire stylesheet boils down to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <ns5:taskListResponse>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/tns:taskListResponse/task:task" />
  </ns5:taskListResponse>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="task:task">
  <ns7:task><xsl:apply-templates select="*" /></ns7:task>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="task:*">
  <xsl:element name="ns7:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

It gets slightly more complex if you do need to re-order things, then you'll need 100 separate `<xsl:apply-templates select="task:foo" />` in place of the `<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />`, but it's still smaller and more modular.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the response.
This xsl that you've given, when applied is copying only the first level elements with the namespace prefix. If there are children for an element, then all the values in that children are copied as one tag

I want to copy the entire structure as it is with the namespace prefix.


Also, there are some attributes whose children have a different namespace, say ns9. In such cases, how do we do.

Basically, I want a replace of ns1 with ns1', ns2 with ns2', etc.

Apprecicate your response

Comment: @user3580661 I can only go on what you put in the question - your example only processes the first level children of `task:task` and all the results go into the same namespace.  To keep processing children you probably want to use `<xsl:apply-templates/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` on the relevant elements, and to handle other namespaces you could add similar templates for `ns2:*` producing an `<xsl:element name="ns9:{local-name()}">` etc.